# Time Limit Exceeded - Simple Program - Divisibility Test

Tags: c++, cin

**Input**
The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=10^7). The next n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than 10^9, each.

**Output**
Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are divisible by k.

**Example**

Input:

```
7 3
1
51
966369
7
9
999996
11
```

Output:

```
4
```

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


long long n,k, i;
cin>>n;
cin>>k;
int count=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int z;
    cin>>z;
    if(z%k == 0) count++;
}
cout<<count;

return 0;
}
```

Now this code produces the correct output. However, its not being accepted by CodeChef(http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST) for the following reason: Time Limit Exceeded. How can this be further optimized?

Comment: You could read shashidhar.msk 's comment in the page you provided.

Comment: Try adding `cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` before the other code. It typically improves speed with iostreams, especially with gcc (makes little or no difference with some compilers, such as MS VC++).

Answer (score 2):

As said by caleb the problem is labeled "**Enormous Input Test**" so it requires you to use some better/faster I/O methods

just replacing  **cout**  with **printf**  and **cin** with **scanf** will give you an AC but to improve your execution time you need to use some faster IO method for example reading character by character using getchar_unlocked() will give you a better execution time

so you can read the values by using a function like this , for a better execution time.

```
 inline int read(){
    char c=getchar_unlocked();
    int n=0;
    while(!(c>='0' && c<='9'))
     c=getchar_unlocked();
    while(c>='0' && c<='9'){
     n=n*10 + (c-'0');
    c=getchar_unlocked();
}
return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The linked problem contains the following description:

> The purpose of this problem is to verify whether the method you are
>   using to read input data is sufficiently fast to handle problems
>   branded with the enormous Input/Output warning. You are expected to be
>   able to process at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime.

Considering that, reading values from input a few bytes at a time using iostreams isn't going to cut it. I googled around a bit and found [a drop-in replacement for `cin` and `cout` described on CodeChef](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/6677/cool-fast-io-implementation). Some other approaches you could try include using a [memory-mapped file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5f38%5f0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped%5ffile.html) and using stdio.

It might also help to look for ways to optimize the calculation. For example, if t<sub>i</sub> < k, then you know that k is not a factor of t<sub>i</sub>. Depending on the magnitude of k and the distribution of t<sub>i</sub> values, that observation alone could save a lot of time.

Remember: the fact that your code is *short* doesn't mean that it's *fast*.